# geometric distribution $ E(e^{tX})$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I consider X as random variable with geometric distribution. That means: $$P(X=k)= (1-p)^{k-1} \cdot p$$ 
I want to calculate: $E(e^{tX})=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{tk}   (1-p)^{k-1} \cdot p $

Is there a way to simplify that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Your can write it as: $$pe^t\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r^k$$where $r:=e^t(1-p)$.

Comment: Then I would get: $$\frac{pe^t}{1-(e^t(1-p)}$$

Comment: Is there a way to simplify that further?

Comment: Not really. You could at most write it more concisely as $\frac{pe^t}{1-qe^t}$ where $p+q=1$. It is the moment generating function of [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

Answer (score 0):

This question amounts to compute the sum of $x^k$ for k from 1 to $\infty$. Recall that this sum is $\frac{1}{1-x}$ when $|x|<1$, equal to $+\infty$ when $x\geq 1$ and does not converge otherwise. In your case $x=e^{t}(1-p)$, so the final answer depends on the value of $t$. You have to check whether $t$ satisfies or not the condition : $t> \ln(1-p)$.